# DSLs - groovy versus xtext

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, dsl, xtext

I an well versed with Java. I have few usecases that benefit from a DSL. Before I start on building them, I would like to take input from people who already built them. Can someone help  me understand what are pros and cons of writing DSL's in Groovy and xtext.

Comment: You need to be very clear what you mean by "DSL". Have you seen the famous 10-question checklist at http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2007/05/the_is_it_a_dsl_or_an_api_ten.html ? Many languages "enable DSL's" by enabling minimally working examples. Groovy at Codehaus, for example, doesn't allow their command expressions inside function calls, making it virtually useless.

Comment: @VorgvanGeir Can you explain _"...doesn't allow their command expressions inside function calls..."_?

Comment: You should list your use cases, since it really depends on them whether a DSL pays of or well designed API is sufficient.

Comment: @tim_yates println(println "a") doesn't parse

Comment: @VorgvanGeir Ahh, I see, you mean omiting the braces on the internal call...  (as `println( println( 'a' ) )` parses ok)

Comment: @tim_yates println(println('a')) parses ok but it's no longer a command expression. Command expressions don't work inside parens or brackets. Virtually every Groovy demo pitching it as a DSL uses an example of a paren-free function call at the top level only. The marketing for Groovy 1.8 made a big fuss about enabling them after the = sign also, but they don't work when nested anywhere.